# Updating a JavaScript object array by matching item in second JavaScript object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry to ask but my head is in pieces. I have two very similar object arrays (I'd simplified my problem / example here rather than use the actual data I am working with to reduce the code) I wish my first array to loop through the second item, determine if the ID of the current objects matches an ID of an item in the second array and if there is a match the price property of the array item from the first array is updated to the value of the price of the matching object in the second array. So for example the firstArray object with the id value of 1 would have its price updated to 25 as that is the price in the object with a matching ID in the second object... phew!

```
var firstArray = [
    {id:"1", name: "Shirt", price: "15.00"},
    {id:"2", name: "Pants", price: "30.00"},
    {id:"3", name: "Socks", price: "8.00"},
    {id:"4", name: "Gloves", price: "5.00"},
    {id:"5", name: "Shirt", price: "16.00" }
];

var secondArray = [
    {id:"1", name: "Shirt", price: "25.00"},
    {id:"2", name: "Pants", price: "40.00"},
    {id:"3", name: "Socks", price: "12.00"},
    {id:"4", name: "Gloves", price: "6.00"},
    {id:"5", name: "Shirt", price: "21.00"},
    {id:"6", name: "Hat", price: "30.00" }
];
```

I don't want to use loops and I'd rather use functional programming using .filter or .map... I just can't think how to do this. Any advice would be appreciated.

I am confused if I should `.filter` or `.map`? Looping through the first array seems easy, it is checking against the second array that is making my head itch.

I'm currently trying this myself but people here are usually faster and smarter than myself and suggest more eloquent solutions.

Comment: Just fyi `.filter or .map` uses loops internally. Actually the are looping mechanism

Comment: I'm currently using filter, the introduction of the second array is the part I am struggling with

Comment: i’m on mobile, but maybe `arr2.filter (e => arr1.filter(f => (f.id == e.id).length))`

Comment: *I am working with to reduce the code*, I understand when you get stuck, you play a lot making code scattered and ugly. But still, if you can share your attempt, it would be great.

Comment: @Rajesh It filters every item in array2 ehich is not contained in array1. op basically wants a join or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` method to create new array and `find` to search for object with same id in other array.

```js
const firstArray = [{"id":"1","name":"Shirt","price":"15.00"},{"id":"2","name":"Pants","price":"30.00"},{"id":"3","name":"Socks","price":"8.00"},{"id":"4","name":"Gloves","price":"5.00"},{"id":"5","name":"Shirt","price":"16.00"}]
const secondArray = [{"id":"1","name":"Shirt","price":"25.00"},{"id":"2","name":"Pants","price":"40.00"},{"id":"3","name":"Socks","price":"12.00"},{"id":"4","name":"Gloves","price":"6.00"},{"id":"5","name":"Shirt","price":"21.00"},{"id":"6","name":"Hat","price":"30.00"}]

const result = firstArray.map(o => {
  const obj = secondArray.find(e => e.id == o.id);
  return Object.assign({}, o, obj && {price: obj.price})
})

console.log(result)
```

You could also create `Map` with `id-price` as key-value and use it later to match ids.

```js
const firstArray = [{"id":"1","name":"Shirt","price":"15.00"},{"id":"2","name":"Pants","price":"30.00"},{"id":"3","name":"Socks","price":"8.00"},{"id":"4","name":"Gloves","price":"5.00"},{"id":"5","name":"Shirt","price":"16.00"}]
const secondArray = [{"id":"1","name":"Shirt","price":"25.00"},{"id":"2","name":"Pants","price":"40.00"},{"id":"3","name":"Socks","price":"12.00"},{"id":"4","name":"Gloves","price":"6.00"},{"id":"5","name":"Shirt","price":"21.00"},{"id":"6","name":"Hat","price":"30.00"}]

const m = new Map(secondArray.map(({id, price}) => [id, price]))
const result = firstArray.map(e => Object.assign({}, e, m.has(e.id) && {price: m.get(e.id)}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Ah, so a nested find in the way!

Comment: Nice answer. Just 1 problem `.find` will loop over secondArray multiple times. Using a hashMap would reduce iterations a lot

Comment: @Rajesh Yes in each iteration of `map` this will run `find` method but at least `find` will stop when the first match is found, and if the data isn't too large it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and colect all new prices and then update the frist array.

```js
var firstArray = [{ id: "1", name: "Shirt", price: "15.00" }, { id: "2", name: "Pants", price: "30.00" }, { id: "3", name: "Socks", price: "8.00" }, { id: "4", name: "Gloves", price: "5.00" }, { id: "5", name: "Shirt", price: "16.00" }],
 secondArray = [{ id: "1", name: "Shirt", price: "25.00" }, { id: "2", name: "Pants", price: "40.00" }, { id: "3", name: "Socks", price: "12.00" }, { id: "4", name: "Gloves", price: "6.00" }, { id: "5", name: "Shirt", price: "21.00" }, { id: "6", name: "Hat", price: "30.00" }];

firstArray.forEach(
    (m => o => m.has(o.id) && (o.price = m.get(o.id)))
        (secondArray.reduce((m, { id, price }) => m.set(id, price), new Map))
);

console.log(firstArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `forEach` and `findIndex` functions.

```js
const firstArray = [     {id:"1", name: "Shirt", price: "15.00"},     {id:"2", name: "Pants", price: "30.00"},     {id:"3", name: "Socks", price: "8.00"},     {id:"4", name: "Gloves", price: "5.00"},     {id:"5", name: "Shirt", price: "16.00" } ];

const secondArray = [     {id:"1", name: "Shirt", price: "25.00"},     {id:"2", name: "Pants", price: "40.00"},     {id:"3", name: "Socks", price: "12.00"},     {id:"4", name: "Gloves", price: "6.00"},     {id:"5", name: "Shirt", price: "21.00"},     {id:"6", name: "Hat", price: "30.00" } ];

firstArray.forEach((i) => {
  var index = secondArray.findIndex((ii) => i.id === ii.id);
  if (index > -1) secondArray[index].price = i.price;
});

console.log(secondArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Idea

- Create an object that will hold price for a given id
- Loop over you array and check if the id exists in map.

  - If yes, set this value
  - If not, return current value.

```js
var firstArray = [{ id: "1", name: "Shirt", price: "15.00" }, { id: "2", name: "Pants", price: "30.00" }, { id: "3", name: "Socks", price: "8.00" }, { id: "4", name: "Gloves", price: "5.00" }, { id: "5", name: "Shirt", price: "16.00" }],
 secondArray = [{ id: "1", name: "Shirt", price: "25.00" }, { id: "2", name: "Pants", price: "40.00" }, { id: "3", name: "Socks", price: "12.00" }, { id: "4", name: "Gloves", price: "6.00" }, { id: "5", name: "Shirt", price: "21.00" }, { id: "6", name: "Hat", price: "30.00" }];

var idPriceMap = secondArray.reduce(function(acc, item){
  acc[item.id] = item.price;
  return acc;
}, {});

var result = firstArray.map(function(item){
  return Object.assign({}, item, { price: (idPriceMap[item.id] || irem.price)});
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
firstArray.forEach(function(e){
  var m = secondArray.find(function(f){ return f.id === e.id; });
  e.price = m ? m.price || e.price;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update price for every item, then I would suggest you to build an index first and then use it. This way you won't need to iterate multiple times over secondArray.

```
//using computed property name
const prices = secondArray.reduce((result, item) => Object.assign(result, { [item.id]: item.price }), {});

//or without
const prices = secondArray.reduce((result, item) => {
    result[item.id] = item.price;
    return result;
}, {});

// update prices in place
firstArray.forEach((item) => item.price = prices[item.id] === undefined ? item.price : prices[item.id])

// or use map to get a new array
const result = firstArray.map((item) => Object.assign({}, item, { price: prices[item.id] }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. You said You do not want loops but I think this is cleanest version possible and you can reuse it

```
var firstArray = [
    {id:"1", name: "Shirt", price: "15.00"},
    {id:"2", name: "Pants", price: "30.00"},
    {id:"3", name: "Socks", price: "8.00"},
    {id:"4", name: "Gloves", price: "5.00"},
    {id:"5", name: "Shirt", price: "16.00" }
];

var secondArray = [
    {id:"1", name: "Shirt", price: "25.00"},
    {id:"2", name: "Pants", price: "40.00"},
    {id:"3", name: "Socks", price: "12.00"},
    {id:"4", name: "Gloves", price: "6.00"},
    {id:"5", name: "Shirt", price: "21.00"},
    {id:"6", name: "Hat", price: "30.00" }
]


fnUpdater(firstArray,secondArray,"id","price")


function fnUpdater(oldArray,newArray,matchProperty,replaceProperty){
    for(let x=0; x<oldArray.length; x++){
        for(let y=0; y<oldArray.length; y++){
            if(oldArray[x].id==newArray[y].id){
                oldArray[x][replaceProperty]=newArray[y][replaceProperty];
            }
        }
    }
}
```